# Problemas na incrementação de uma pontuação / contador

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

Olá, boa noite ! Estou tentando criar um placar para um jogo, onde nele consta dois tipos diferentes de pontuações 2 e 5 pontos. O meu maior problema é que não consigo atualizar constantemente o valor do placar a cada click no Submit. O valor é apenas substituido ao inves de somar com ele mesmo.Sei que a pergunta é besta mas realmente preciso de ajuda ! Obrigado.

```js
//Global variables
let randomRound;
init();

//Logica do button-start-game
document
  .querySelector(".button-start-game").addEventListener("click",function() {
    document.querySelector(".button-submit").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".button-next-round").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".button-start-game").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".button-next-round").style.position = "relative";
    document.querySelector(".button-next-round").style.left = "150px";
    document.querySelector(".button-submit").style.position = "relative";
    document.querySelector(".button-submit").style.left = "150px";
    
    randomRounds();
  });

// Logica do button-next-round
document.querySelector(".button-next-round").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // randomiza um numero
    //1.Gera um round aleatorio
    //2. Mostra o round dentro da label

    randomRounds(randomRound);
    document.getElementById("button-submit").disabled = false;

    refresh();
  });

function refresh() {
  document.getElementById("input-0").value = "";
  document.getElementById("input-1").value = "";

  
}

// Logica do button-submit
document.querySelector(".button-submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //1. Compara o Input com o Random round
  //2. Mostra uma ponntuacao baseada nessa comparacao
  //3. Atualiza o Score

  if (document.getElementById("input-0").value == "" && document.getElementById("input-0").value == "") {
    alert("Preencha o campo");
  } else {
    let firstInput = document.getElementById("input-0").value;
    let secondInput = document.getElementById("input-1").value;
    checker(firstInput, secondInput);
  }



});

// Função que inicia o game
function init() {
  roundScore = [0];
  document.querySelector(".button-start-game").style.position = "relative";
  document.querySelector(".button-start-game").style.left = "300px";
  document.querySelector(".button-submit").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".button-next-round").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("input-0").value = "";
  document.getElementById("input-1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("score-0").textContent = "0";
}

function randomRounds(round) {
  randomRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;

  console.log("%c Rounds Function", "color:Orange; font-weigth:bold;");
  if (randomRound === 1) {
    console.log("%c Rounds1", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");

    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "2³";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "3²";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "1¹";
  } else if (randomRound === 2) {
    console.log("%c Rounds2", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "(-2)²";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "4¹";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "1⁴";
  } else if (randomRound === 3) {
    console.log("%c Rounds3", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "(2²)³";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "2⁴.2²";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "(2³)²";
  } else if (randomRound === 4) {
    console.log("%c Rounds4", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "5³:5^-1";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "5²";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "25^-1";
  } else if (randomRound === 5) {
    console.log("%c Rounds5", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "(3.10²) + (4.10²)";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "7.10²";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "7.10⁴";
  } else if (randomRound === 6) {
    console.log("%c Rounds6", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "(6.10)² . (2.10)⁴";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "12.10⁴";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "(12.10⁵):10¹";
  } else if (randomRound === 7) {
    console.log("%c Rounds7", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "0,0000001";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "10^-8";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "1/10^9";
  } else if (randomRound === 8) {
    console.log("%c Rounds8", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "2.0,001";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "0,002";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "2.10^-3";
  } else if (randomRound === 9) {
    console.log("%c Rounds9", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "250 000";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "0,25.10⁷ ";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "25.10⁵";
  } else if (randomRound === 10) {
    console.log("%c Rounds10", "color:red; font-weigth:bold;");
    document.getElementById("place-holder-1").textContent = "100²:10³";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-2").textContent = "1/10^-1";
    document.getElementById("place-holder-3").textContent = "10^-2";
  } else {
    console.log("Not a Round !");
  }
}

function scoreCopy(src) {
  return Object.assign({}, src);
}

function checker(input1, input2) {
  scoreCopy();
  let valueA =0;
  let valueB=0;
  const score = { a: valueA, b: valueB };
  const newScore = scoreCopy(score);

  if (input1 === "<" && input2 === "<") {
    console.log("%c Adiciona 5", "color:Purple; font-weigth:bold;");
    score.a = score.a +5;
    document.getElementById("score-0").innerHTML = score.a;
    console.table(score);
    document.getElementById("button-submit").disabled = true;

  } else if (input1 === "<" || input2 === "<") {
    console.log("%c Adiciona 2", "color:Purple; font-weigth:bold;");
    score.b = score.b +2;
    console.table(score);    
    document.getElementById("score-0").innerHTML = score.b;
    document.getElementById("button-submit").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url(./../img/clouds-2.png);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  max-width: 292px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 5px;
  place-self: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 290px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%);
  max-width: 290px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
}
.head,
.middle,
.bottom,
.sinais {
  margin: 5px;
  place-self: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 290px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%);
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
}

.head:hover,
.middle:hover,
.bottom:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc55 100%);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.grid-game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
  gap: 1px;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.place-holder,
.input-0,.input-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  place-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%);
}

.grid-buttons {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  right: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10%;
  gap: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button-submit,.button-next-round,.button-start-game {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%);
}
.button-submit:active,.button-next-round:active,.button-start-game:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.button-submit:hover,.button-next-round:hover,.button-start-game:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc4f 100%);
}

.score-grid {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 10%;
  gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.score-field,.score {
  box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e0c3fc 0%, #8ec5fc 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Match Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="grid">
        <h1>Match Game</h1>
        <div class="sinais">Sinais</div>
        <div class="head">></div>
        <div class="middle">=</div>
        <div class="bottom"><</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-game">
        <div class="place-holder" id="place-holder-1">A</div>
        <input type="text" class="input-0" id="input-0" />
        <div class="place-holder" id="place-holder-2">B</div>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" id="input-1" />
        <div class="place-holder" id="place-holder-3">C</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-buttons">
        <button class="button-submit" id="button-submit">Submit</button>
        <button class="button-start-game">Start Game</button>
        <button class="button-next-round">Next Round</button>
      </div>

      <div class="score-grid">
        <div class="score">Score</div>
        <div class="score-field" id="score-0">0</div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="./app.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: não li seu codigo todo mas, se está usando um botão submit, esse não irá postar a pagina, o que causa o reload e perde os contadores de score? é preciso mesmo ser um submit, ou poderia ser um simples button?

Comment: Olá , Ricardo . Pode ser apenas um button qualquer , contanto que o score seja armazenado e o valor atualizado. Ex : uma rodade eu tiro 5 e na outra eu tiro 2  então na terceira rodada eu tenho que ter 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o problema está na parte do código da função `checker`:

```
function checker(input1, input2) { 
    scoreCopy(); 
    let valueA =0; 
    let valueB=0; 
    const score = { a: valueA, b: valueB };
    //...
}
```

Toda vez que o botão é clicado e os valores dos inputs são analisados, você reinicia a variável `score`. Ou seja, independente do valor anterior do placar, ele sempre vai ser reiniciado para 0, fazendo com que sempre apareça o mesmo valor.

A sugestão que dou é colocar o `const score = {a: valorA, b: valorB};` lá no topo do arquivo, fazendo com que ele seja inicializado apenas uma vez, e a partir daí ele fica reutilizando o valor que já está armazenado.

E outra: na *callback* de clique do botão `button-submit`, você colocou para testar duas vezes se o `#input-0` possui valor vazio:

```
document.querySelector(".button-submit").addEventListener("click", function() { 
    //1. Compara o Input com o Random round 
    //2. Mostra uma ponntuacao baseada nessa comparacao 
    //3. Atualiza o Score 

    //AQUI
    if (document.getElementById("input-0").value == "" && document.getElementById("input-0").value == "") { 
        alert("Preencha o campo"); 
    } else { 
        let firstInput = document.getElementById("input-0").value; 
        let secondInput = document.getElementById("input-1").value; 
        checker(firstInput, secondInput); 
    } 



});
```

Acho que você quis digitar "input-1" no outro.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito Obrigado ! Era erro de escopo mesmo. Desculpa pelo seu tempo , até mais !